# Global CSS doesn’t work when programmatically change route

Tags: vue.js

My index page has a Header and Home components.

```
{
        path: "/",
        name: "Homepage",
        components: {
            header: () => import("../components/layout/HomepageHeader.vue"),
            main: () => import("../views/Home.vue"),
    },
},
```

Both don’t have any scoped CSS, they only use Tailwind CSS classes. And that Tailwind CSS file is global.
The problem occurs when I programmatically redirect to my index page (for example, after I logged in). The **HomepageHeader** component doesn’t have all the CSS. Same with the **Home.vue** component.
Here’s the simplified code of the Header

```
<template>
    <div class="w-full bg-white sm:shadow-lg mb-6">
        <div class="mx-6">
            <nav
                class="px-3 flex flex-col sm:flex-row sm:px-4 sm:justify-between sm:h-16 list-none"
            >
                <li
                    class="text-center h-16 font-semibold text-red-500 text-lg sm:text-xl sm:h-16 table"
                >
                    <div class=" py-4 sm:h-16">
                        <router-link to="/">Home</router-link>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <login-badge
                        class="shadow-lg md:shadow-none px-4 py-3 flex sm:px-0 sm:h-14 text-white"
                    ></login-badge>
                </li>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

When I say

```
“component doesn’t have all the CSS”
```

I mean that all the classes in the **HomepageHeader.vue** component don’t work. But the classes inside the child component **LoginBadge.vue** work fine!

What else can I say? I use `router.replace("/");` to redirect to the homepage.
How do I fix that?

P.S. Just found out that the same thing happends when I go back to a previous page and that previous page is the index page.

P.P.S. global CSS is imported inside the App.vue

```
<template>
    <router-view name="header"></router-view>
    <main class="container mx-auto">
        <router-view name="main"></router-view>
    </main>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    setup() {
        return {};
    },
};
</script>

<style>
@import "./assets/tailwind.css";
```

Comment: Are you importing your "global" styles directly inside `Login.vue`? Show where and how you import styles?

Comment: @MatJ Added some more code. Please take a look. I found out that everytime I use router to navigate or when I go back to a previous page this problem occurs. But navigation with router-link work fine

Comment: Can you move the style import from `style` tag to `script` tag(remove the `@` when you do so) and check if it works

Comment: it didn't work :(

Comment: I made a redirection to another page with the same header. And on that another page (not index page) it work incorrectly too. Also on that another page all the elements have correct style unless the <router-link> element. It has the default styles of <a> tag. Only after refreshing the page it get the correct styles

Comment: The behavior seems to be pointing at local import of css. You insist that is not the case, without an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), I cannot help any further. On your network tab in your browser and navigate to a problematic page, see if css is requested, check the style tags in the document, see if the style appear in there.

Comment: @MatJ I finally got it!!!! It happens to everythin that is going to be converted to normal html. For example, <router-link> won't be styled after redirecting with router. But all other native elements will!! So what's the problem then?

Comment: router-link is a placeholder, apply styles to a wrapping div instead?

Comment: @MatJ write the same as an answer and I'll mark it as a solution.Thanks for the hint!!!